# how del list[:] works

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

`list[:]` creates a copy of the list then why does `del list[:]` remove all the list items?

Shouldn't it delete the copy of the list?

Comment: Think of it as `list[:]` "returning" all the items in the list (and it happens to return them in a new list).  Then `del list[:]` clearing the same items in the list is more obvious.

Comment: because the expression `list[:]` is different from the statement `del list[:]`. The former does not mutate the list, while the latter does. Similarly, `list[x:y] = z` is a mutates the list. Note, `del` never deletes an object. It deletes names.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  This question would seem to be a perfect counterexample to the confusing statement *"`del` never deletes an object. It deletes names."* what names are being deleted in slice deletion? What names are being deleted in descriptor's `__del__` invocation, e.g. a property deleter?  It only deletes names if the operand was a name!

Comment: @wim sorry, yes, I see that what I'm saying is confusing. To clarify, I mean is that in the simple case of `del x` the `del` keyword acts to delete a name, not the object being referenced by the name. Using `del` on anything other than a name will be defined by that object via it's `__delitem__` method, or via `__delattr__` or via the `__delete__` method on a descriptor of the class. Note, even in that case, it doesn't delete objects, but yes, my statement is wrongly worded.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, it shouldn't. It's intended to delete all of the elements of the list. Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), the result of `s.clear()` (where `s` is a mutable sequence type, for example a `list`) is:

> removes all items from s (same as `del s[:]`)

Hence, `del s[:]` is the same as `s.clear()` in that it removes all items from `s`.

Perhaps, this is a bit more understandable if you consider that the function called behind the scenes is `__delitem__`. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__):

> Called to implement deletion of `self[key]`. Same note as for `__getitem__()`. This should only be implemented for mappings if the objects support removal of keys, or for sequences if elements can be removed from the sequence. The same exceptions should be raised for improper key values as for the `__getitem__()` method.

Consider the following difference:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = a

del a
# print(a) ## raises an error
print(b)   ## prints [1,2,3]

c = [1,2,3]
d = c

del c[:]
print(c)   ## prints []
print(d)   ## prints []
```

So why would you want `del a[:]` to behave this way? Well, think of it as just a special case of deleting a slice of a list. For example, say that you'd want to delete the 3rd, 4th, and 5th element of a long list `a = list(range(40))`. With the slice notation and the `__delitem__` this is easy, just use `del a[3:6]`. Now try to do the same with a `for` loop and you'll soon find out it can get quite cumbersome. Heck, just try to delete all the items of `a` (but not the `a` itself!) with a `for` loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because `a[:]` is is simply just a copy of `a`, consisting of the identical objects as `a` but a different object than `a`. Their elements are identical but they are not.

Let's create a list and do some `id` checks:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(a)) # 97731118088
print(id(a[:])) # 97731213576
print(id(a[:])) # 97731212104
print(id(a[:])) # 97731198600
```

Notice the changing `id`s of the copy `a[:]`. It is an object that is created on the fly every time it is called, and most importantly, even `a[:] is a[:]` not `True`! Let's look at the `id`s of their elements to come to a conclusion:

```
print(id(a[0])) # 1648192992
print(id(a[:][0])) # 1648192992
a[0] is a[:][0] # True
a[1] is a[:][1] # True
a[2] is a[:][2] # True
```

So, we can conclude that `a[:]` is an object that consists of the very elements of `a` but is a different object than `a`, and is a different object every time it is called. The elements of `a` and `a[:]` are all identical, but they themselves are not.

So what `del a[:]` does is to remove all of the **elements of** `a`. That way `a` is mutated, and you end up with an empty `a`, i.e. `[]`. However, `del a` removes the name `a` from namespace completely, and when you ask Python to print `a` for you, you'll get a `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

**But how do we know that?** Well, let's gain some perspective by disassembling `del` on `a` vs `a[:]`:

Let's define two functions:

```
def deletion1(a):
    del a

def deletion2(a):
    del a[:]
```

Let's disassemble them:

```
import dis

dis.dis(x = deletion1)

  1           0 DELETE_FAST              0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(x = deletion2)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 BUILD_SLICE              2
              8 DELETE_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [dis documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) indicates that the `DELETE_FAST` operation, which the first function does, simply "Deletes local `co_varnames[var_num]`". This is basically removal of that name `a` so that you can't reach the list object anymore. Beware, **this does not remove the object that is referred to by the name a**, but just removes its name so that the `a` is not a reference to anything anymore. The object `97731118088` is still the same list, `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
import gc
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if id(obj) == 97731118088:
        print(obj)
        # [1, 2, 3]
```

On the other hand, again from the documentation, `DELETE_SUBSCR` "Implements `del TOS1[TOS]`", which is basically "an in-place operator that removes the top of the stack and pushes the result back on the stack". This way, the stack elements are removed, and you are left with the name `a`, which now refers to a list whose elements are deleted, i.e. just an "empty shell", if you will. After this operation, `a` becomes `[]`, but has still the same `id` of 97731118088. Just its elements are gone via an in-place deletion.

Comment: "Because a[:] is not a copy of the list a. It is simply all of the elements inside it." I don't understand the distinction you are trying to make here. `a is not a[:]`. To be precise, the result of the expression `a[:]` is a new list object that is a copy (expressed as a full slice) of the list object being referred to by the name `a`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, bad wording, I'll edit that piece.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please see the updated answer, which I tried to make a thorough one by going to the specifics of `id`s and disassembling the functions.